# Prestashop PHP import customized value Features

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to add some custom Features in Prestashop v. 1.6.

I have managed to import Pre-defined values, using the ID's of the Features, but now I have a large list of Features that I want to import, but this time I don't have ID's for them, and I want them imported onto the Customized value inside Prestashop Features.

This is the code for assigning features inside my importer:

```
foreach ($customProductObject->features as $feature) {
            Product::addFeatureProductImport($product->id, $feature['id'], $feature['value']);
        }
```

This is the code I use for assigning a Feature to it's respective ID inside Prestashop.

```
$features[] = ['id' => 11, 'value' => 192];
```

The **11** is the ID of a Feature in Prestashop (In my case: **SIZE**) and 192 is the ID of the Value (In my case: **LARGE**).

**My question is this: How can I do this if I want to assign a value of a feature, but it is not stored in an already Pre-defined Value inside Prestashop?**

Example: I want to assign a new feature (In my case: Colour, with id 12), with a custom value (In my case: red, blue, etc), but for which I don't have an ID, because it isn't stored in a Pre-defined value inside Prestashop, it will be a Customized value, inserted directly from a feed.

I tried this, with no success:

```
$features[] = ['id' => 12, 'value' => 'red'];
```